# Failed using scale_npp ffmpeg filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying on Windows 10 (through MinGW64) to convert (mixing mode) from x265 file (by CPU) to x264 (by GPU - NVidia) resizing the output using scale_npp.

What do the last five rows in this log mean?

```
     $ ffmpeg -i /i/_wip/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MULTI.1080p.BDRip.x265.10bit.AAC.2.0.Subs.Fr.Eng.mkv -c:v h264_nvenc -an -vf "fade,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=304:120" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast /i/_wip/test1_output_h264.mp4
        ffmpeg version N-98027-g89328022be-g6cd198860d+3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
          built with gcc 10.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
          configuration:  --cc='ccache gcc' --cxx='ccache g++' --disable-autodetect --enable-bzlib --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-iconv --enable-lzma --enable-nvenc --enable-zlib --enable-sdl2 --
        enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libdav1d --disable-debug --enable-fontconfig --enable-libass
         --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
        ble-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libshine --enable-gpl --enable-avisynth --enable-libxvid --enable-libopenmpt --enable-version3 --enable-decklink --enable-frei0
        r --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libflite --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libsvthevc --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmodplug --e
        nable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libtesseract --enable-libxavs --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-libvmaf --enable-libsrt --enable-ladspa --enable-librav1e --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --
        enable-libnpp --enable-libopenh264 --enable-openssl --extra-cflags=-fopenmp --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-libs=-lstdc++ --extra-cflags=-DCACA_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DMODPLUG_STATIC --extra-cfla
        gs=-DZMQ_STATIC --extra-libs=-lpsapi --extra-cflags=-DLIBXML_STATIC --extra-libs=-liconv --disable-w32threads --extra-cflags=-DKVZ_STATIC_LIB --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags='-IC:/PROGRA~1/NVIDIA~2/CUDA/v10.2/include' --extra-
        ldflags='-LC:/PROGRA~1/NVIDIA~2/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64'
          libavutil      56. 49.100 / 56. 49.100
          libavcodec     58. 90.100 / 58. 90.100
          libavformat    58. 44.100 / 58. 44.100
          libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
          libavfilter     7. 84.100 /  7. 84.100
          libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
          libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
          libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
        [matroska,webm @ 000001b7772d1980] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
        Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
        [matroska,webm @ 000001b7772d1980] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
        Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
        Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'I:/_wip/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MULTI.1080p.BDRip.x265.10bit.AAC.2.0.Subs.Fr.Eng.mkv':
          Metadata:
            ...
            ...
            ...
              _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v35.0.0 ('All The Love In The World') 64-bit
              _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-25 20:17:47
              _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        Stream mapping:
          Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
        Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

        **Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_scale_npp_2' and the filter 'auto_scaler_1'
        Error reinitializing filters!
        Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
        Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
        Conversion failed!**
```

Answer (score 0):

scale_npp not work with 10bit video stream. Use scale_cuda or just place "-pix_fmt yuv420p" before filters